# ListData.svc appends the library title with 0?

Tags: 2010, listdata.svc

It seems that if i create the following libraries on a Sharepoint site:

- `Test Library 2`
- `Test Library2`
- `TestLibrary2`

then the ListData.svc will return the following entitites:

- `<collection href="TestLibrary2">
  <atom:title>TestLibrary2</atom:title> </collection>`
- `<collection href="TestLibrary20">
  <atom:title>TestLibrary20</atom:title> </collection>`
- `<collection href="TestLibrary21">
  <atom:title>TestLibrary21</atom:title> </collection>`

However, i can then go back and create a `Test Library 20`, which will be returned as `<collection href="TestLibrary200">
<atom:title>TestLibrary200</atom:title>
</collection>`.

This annoyes me quite a bit, since i can not rely on the entities returned by the service, which means that i can not say what exactly is the name, title, basetemplate etc. of the list.

Is there any way to obtain any of this information using SP2010 REST API?
(Yes, i know in 2013 the client.svc aka /_api/ is awesomely powerful, about as much as CSOM).